# Nodejs API development -Best practice of versioning the API

Tags: node.js, versioning, api-design

I need to develop an API using NodeJS.But I am not an expert in the nodejs. For the versioning of the API, I found one method where we should keep 2 folders for V1 and V2 versions. Is this the best practise to follow for my API development. Please suggest the best approach? Also suggest the project structure.

Answer (score 2):

You should keep the API version as a variable that is configurable (ex. in `.env` file). You can then version your API by adding the version to the path of your root endpoint (ex. `/my-api/v1/api-resource`). And when a new version of the API is developed just change the version to `v2`.

I think that solution of two different directories is not good, because you would have to copy code around and it can quickly mess things up. If you want to have different versions of the API separated you should use some type of version control and develop your `v1` on a separate branch (ex. `v1`) and when the development of that version is complete just create a new branch for the new version (ex. `v2`).

You should also look into REST as the architectural style of your API: https://restfulapi.net/

I have also created a [template for the development of backend systems in Node.js](https://github.com/anzemur/api-seed) that is based on REST architecture, so you can check out the directory structure and architecture of Node.js projects.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.Is it possible to run both V1 and V2 URL at the same time

Comment: We are new to node js. So we decided to write .js file . How we can handle multiple versions in the same nodejs api application?

Comment: @KrishnachandranES You can run both version of the api as seperate deploymentwith different settings.